# Check if a callback is being called

Tags: javascript, callback, asynccallback

I have a library that uses callbacks to work (assume I can't edit the functions of that library).

I would like to be able to know if a callback has been called, and if not, do something.

Here is a quick MCVE to expose my issue :

```js
const networkError = false;

(function() {
  getUser(name => console.log('Username is', name));

  if(!'Some condition that says if the callback failed')
    console.log('Network error, can not fetch name');
})();

function getUser(callback) {
  if (!networkError) callback('John Doe');
}
```

The end goal would be to manage authentication. I would like to test if the user is connected, and if not, redirect to another page **without the user seeing the logged page content**. Up to now, all I've found is using a Timeout with a boolean that is set in the callback, but that's not stable at all ...

Comment: does the callback gets called in synchronous or is it an asynchronous thing. If asynchronous, how long you want to wait for execution?

Comment: which function you cannot edit getUser or callback in getUser?

Comment: @Ashish It is asynchronous, I would like to make it synchronous (if possible) so that I don't have to play with timeouts.

Comment: @ducmai I can edit the callback, not the functions outside of the IIFE.

Comment: @trichetriche You already told you can only modify the callback function and not the function calling the callback, so if the behavior is async. You cant make it synchronous.

Comment: @Ashish that's what I was afraid of. Except from timeouts, there's no way of resolving this issue, is what you mean ?

Comment: Yes, because your callback getting called asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

You could create two promises, one wrapping your callback, the other one throwing after a certain time, then let them race:

```
 const timeout = time => new Promise((_, reject) => setTimeout(reject, time));

const result = Promise.race([
  new Promise(getUser),
  timeout(1000)
]);

result.then(/*..*/).catch(/*...*/)
```

But actually the API (`getUser`) should also call back with an error if something went wrong.

Comment: Well that's the issue there, I would like not to use timeouts. If I do so, the user will be able to have a glimpse of the page before being redirected.

Comment: Then your API is broken.

Comment: maybe not the API, but definitely the process. Thank you for the input though, I'll try negociating to avoid that solution !